# How would I run a queue of an Amazon SQS ? Is it a cron job?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I understand the basic of Amazon SQS. Yet i'm still confused on how it runs? Is it an infinite running function that polls messages and deal with it? how would I achieve that in php?

What I have in mind is a cron job that triggers the polling and process the messages. is my understanding right?

Comment: I don't think that PHP _could_ be "infinite running"

Comment: Use a process manager like supervisord to keep one or more worker scripts running, and in your worker keep track of how many jobs you've processed and shut down after 1000 or so to make sure PHP's resource usage doesn't go nuts. Supervisord will make sure that there are always workers running.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton PHP can absolutely be infinite running, if run via the CLI.

Comment: @ceejayoz Interesting, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There's more than one answer to this.

Yes, you could have cron poll regularly for new queue items. You could have a daemon running indefinitely (likely monitored by something like supervisor) that continues to poll in a loop.

There's also [SQS triggers](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-lambda-adds-amazon-simple-queue-service-to-supported-event-sources/), where a new SQS item can automatically *initiate* something. There are multiple options available: new queue items can make an SNS notification, which could trigger a HTTP POST to a URL. They can also trigger a Lambda function.

Comment: "new SQS item" .. just to be clear, you mean SQS queue triggers SNS topc every time a message is sent to the queue?

Comment: also if that's the case when will I ever need a process that keeps the queue running?

Comment: @ceejayoz check that: The Lambda service can now poll an SQS queue and invoke a function, but SQS queues don't have any other types of triggers. You can do SNS > SQS but not the other way around.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I'm sorry. But do you mean that SNS does subscribe to SQS?  or not? does it trigger every-time a message is sent?

Comment: You cannot trigger SNS from SQS, @Faisal.  You can do SNS → Lambda, SNS → SQS, and SQS → Lambda... but not SQS → SNS.  The way AWS talks about how these service integrate is sometimes backwards to the way the integration is actually implemented. *Technically,* SQS is not actually capable of triggering anything -- but the Lambda service can be configured to set up managed listeners (on invisible servers they provide for free) to consume messages from an SQS queue and invoke a Lambda function with each message received... which behaves effectively as if SQS is triggering the Lambda function.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot that's clear and is the way I understood it, Thanks. What's your suggestion on the best way to use SQS, a CRON job?